# TCP connection debug log for Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, tcp

One of my services is calling another service. I can't figure out why but sometimes I get a `SocketException: Connection reset`. There are multiple layers between these 2 services. In order to know for sure what's happening, I need to make sure the destination service is not closing the connection. Both services are tomcat/spring boot apps.

How can I make Tomcat log when a TCP connection handshake took place?

I already tried setting `org.apache.catalina` on debug but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Tomcat doesn't have any access to the TCP stack, maybe making a network capture would show who is closing the connection and why (connection timeout vs immediate reset ?)

Comment: Unless you are calling over HTTPS, and then you can use -Djavax.net.debug=all